# Spring Cloud - Finchley.M8 - Refresh Get Operation returns Page Not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-config

I am using Spring Cloud Config server [git repo] with basic authentication and config client

Spring Boot: 2.0.0.RELEASE
Spring Cloud: Finchley.M8

In spring could client when refresh method is posted (http://localhost:8080/refresh) got below error message

```
    {
        "timestamp": "2018-03-04T13:40:36.256+0000",
        "status": 404,
        "error": "Not Found",
        "message": "No message available",
        "path": "/refresh"
    }
```

Comment: According to the boot docs, the new path is under /actuator and needs to be enabled

Comment: actuator is enabled and in the previous versions of spring cloud dependency it works well

Comment: Are you accessing /actuator/refresh? Have you set endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh (property may be wrong, on mobile) see boot documents.

Comment: after adding management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh in properties it worked, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add the below in application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh
```

and hit the new endpoint of the actuator.

```
/actuator/refresh
```